# Send a form without showing results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm doing my first javascript game and I nearly finished it, but the last thing I'd like to add is scoreboard. I've already set a simple database table ([id][author][time]), connection through PDO works perfect, etc..

My game contains a div, where at the end of level jQuery set user's time. This div could be a source of score which I would send to database. And there is a button "Again" which reload whole thing. It could be a form 'sender'.

There is my imaginary work path:

start game > load scoreboard script > finish level > user press "Again", score goes to database > reload page

my problem is if I use at the end:

```
<form method="POST" action="somescript.php"></form>
```

as a result I get somescript.php, but I would like to do this in background, while new game will be loaded.

My question is how to make that script 'quiet' - press "Reload page", script is done in background and I have a new game with updated database?

Comment: can't you just redirect back from somescript.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AJAX for this, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Example:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {

    // Stop form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create AJAX request
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "somescript.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { score: $('#elementthatcontainsscore').val() },
        dataType: "json"
    });

    // Alert whatever is returned from your script
    request.done(function( res ) {
        alert(res);
        // You can reset form stuff here too
    });
});
```

Comment: And in somescript.php will I receive $_POST['score'] ?

Comment: That is correct, you can change type: "POST" to type: "GET" and use $_GET['score'] also if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Look into AJAX Requests.  jQuery's $.ajax is your friend

```
var score = $("#score").text();
$.ajax({
    url: 'somescript.php',
    data: {
        score: score
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        //do something?
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but I would probably just add this at the end of somescript.php

```
$theResults = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href = "http://example.com"
</script>
EOD;

echo "$theResults";
```